# FB Graph API - User is not able to see the comment posted by APP

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-page, facebook-permissions

Using graph api, I'm replying back (comment) to user's posts in our page. I'm passing page access token in the call to post comment and it is getting successful.

When I login with Page admin and open user's post, I can see the comment posted by my app.

But when I login as the test user, I'm not able to see the comment APP has posted.

PFA snapshots.

[FB-Page Admin-Post view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PL9JI.jpg)

[FB-Test user -Page Post view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzDgd.jpg)

Can you please advise on what I'm doing wrong here.

Thank You..

Comment: is your app live? check your settings.

Comment: I'm connecting to FB via Pega and it is for R&D purpose. So our APP is not public/published. What settings I should be checking. 

FYI, I'm pretty new to FB graph API, APPS etc.

Comment: well, check your settings then. it´s under login review, on top.

Comment: Ok. I may not be able to submit the app for review. So, in this case, users won't be able to view comments from FB App as my app need publish permissions? 
Initially I tried creating Test users Authenticated with APP. But, I wasn't able to search for my page using those test user. Even I have unpublished my page so that it won't be public anymore. But still I was not able to search that page with APP Test users. So I have created a Temporary Public user. Is there a way, a test user can work with pages.

Comment: you don´t need to, just set it live

Comment: It Worked :) . Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@luschn's suggestion worked. By setting APP to Live from App settings resolved the issue. Now users are able to view comments posted by my APP.